# download all S&P 500 companies daily highest market price data

Tags: r, download, stocks, price

I want to download all S&P 500 companies daily highest market price data like this by R. What is the esiest way I can do that. data would be like this

```
Date        MSFT    AAPL    GOOGL
25-01-05    21.03   4.87    88.56
26-01-05    21.02   4.89    94.62
27-01-05    21.10   4.91    94.04
28-01-05    21.16   5.00    95.17
31-01-05    21.24   5.20    97.81
```

Comment: Use the code in [Chris Conlan](https://chrisconlan.com/download-daily-data-every-sp-500-stock-r/). Then, after running it, to access, for instance, Microsoft highest prices, just do `DATA[['MSFT']]$High`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantmod provide that functionality.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL"), auto.assign = TRUE, from = "2005-01-05",src="google")
```

Then, just grab the closing price i.e. the second column of each table. It will give you the list of 3 assets closing price.

```
high = lapply(list(AAPL, GOOGL, MSFT), function(x) x[,2])
```

In case you need a matrix:

```
df = data.matrix(as.data.frame(high))
```

Comment: install.packages("quantmod")

Comment: Thanks but can I get all s&p 500 companies together?

Comment: df = data.matrix(as.data.frame(high))

Comment: Thanks. but my question was I only can download three mentioned companies by your code. however it is difficult to write all 500 company name of  s&p500 list in that code.

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli See my comment above. It takes only a few minutes to download them all.

Comment: Don't think there are such functionality. You need to specify it in a vector. You may try to store all symbols in separate file and just pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something similar to this question employing the next code.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(qmao)
library(tidyr)
library(xts)
library(Quandl)
library(quantmod)
first.date <- ("2018/03/01")
last.date <- ("2019/03/31")
df.SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()
tickers <- df.SP500$company
getSymbols(tickers, auto.assign = TRUE, from =first.date, to= last.date  )
rm(first.date,last.date,df.SP500,tickers)
nt<-ls()
ClosePrices <- do.call(merge, lapply(nt, function(x) Cl(get(x))))
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "ClosePrices"))# be carefull this line delets all    other objects from enviroment
```

I hope this can help